# Why does the ProgressBar keep spinning even if the Thread.sleep() was called?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-custom-view, android-progressbar

I made a custom view with animation using **ValueAnimator** and noticed that when performing some heavy operations (which, for some reason, cannot be moved to another thread), the animation freezes. And then, I checked how the **ProgressBar** behaves in such situations: it does not freeze! But looking at the source code of the ProgressBar I could not understand why.

So my question is:
**Why does the ProgressBar keep spinning even if the Thread.sleep () was called?**

Comment: The ProgressBar (and all UI components) runs in another thread, to be able to attend user inputs, animations, and so on. You have to call specifically the API to freeze it.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the ProgressBar is running on the Main Thread which never freezes. You ValueAnimator is running on a separate Thread. That's why it can stop, but the ProgressBar can't.

Comment: No, this is not so, the main thread can be frozen with a heavy operation, such as Thread.sleep (). In addition, ProgressBar uses ObjectAnimator, which inherits from ValueAnimator.